# Solace JMS Channel closing on it's own when running on a Kubernetes cluster (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, jms, solace

So I have a very simple JMS Listener running on Spring Boot, and running on a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud.

The only thing i've defined is the following in my configuration class:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory cFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, JmsErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    logger.info("cFactory called...");
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    factory.setTransactionManager(null);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
    return factory;
}
```

My Application.properties:

```
solace.jms.host=tcps://[host]
solace.jms.clientUsername=[username]
solace.jms.clientPassword=[password]
solace.jms.msgVpn=[msgvpn]
solace.jms.queueName=[queuename]
server.port=8080
logging.level.com.solacesystems=INFO
```

JMS Listener:

```
@JmsListener(destination="${solace.jms.queueName}", containerFactory = "cFactory")
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    [Do stuff with message]
}
```

I have this issue in the logs that says the following:

```
2020-02-28 21:08:40.247  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connecting to host 'orig=tcps://[host goes here], scheme=tcps://, host=[host], port=55443' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 294, attempt 1 of 1, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
2020-02-28 21:07:21.968  INFO 1 --- [enerContainer-1] c.m.a.notam.listener.JmsMessageListener  : Message Received and processed
2020-02-28 21:07:20.572  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.s.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient      : closeOutbound() : isSslDowngradeEnabled: false, mSslEngineClosed: false
2020-02-28 21:07:20.572  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Channel Closed (smfclient 262)
2020-02-28 21:07:20.535  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connected to host 'orig=tcps://[host]:55443, scheme=tcps://, host=[host], port=55443' (smfclient 262)
```

It basically loops like this all day long and I can't figure out why. When I run this locally on my development machine the connection remains open and messages are streaming in just fine.

There is no other log to give me a clue why the channel is closing on its own like this.

Any one have any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: How are you deploying your application to your Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Jenkins X (https://jenkins-x.io/)

Comment: Can you enable more detailed logging for the solace packages, and post that please?

Comment: Do you have access to the logs on the Solace broker, respectively the event log? There should be a corresponding client disconnect entry with a reason for the close that might help you determine where the connections is being closed from (e.g. client itself, broker or something in the network causing it).

Comment: I think the solution here might be to use a CachingConnectionFactory instead of the default. Have you given that a shot?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, even though using CachingConnectionFactory